# I cannot get my website to center

Tags: css

My website will not center no matter what I do to it. I have tried

```
margin: auto 0;
```

I have tried

```
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
```

and the most success I have had is getting the entire website aligned to the right, which is not quite what I was shooting for.

Here's the CSS that controls the alignment of the site, as well as other details. If you could hep me I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
#Content {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 850px;

    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;

    background-color: #006600;

    font-size: 12px;
    font-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: It should be margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I'll go give that a try Andrew.

Comment: Andrew that worked perfectly, I should've known I was just switching something around. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Andrew is right, it should be:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

This is expressing margins in shorthand format. When only 2 values are given, it is interpreted as:

```
margin: (top and bottom value), (left and right value);
```

So

```
margin: 1px 2px;
```

means

```
margin-top: 1px;
margin-bottom: 1px; 
margin-left: 2px;
margin-right: 2px;
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties)

Answer (score 1):

margin:auto; works fine. here check the demo.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDL9f/)

#### [Full Screen Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TDL9f/embedded/result/)

just replace

```
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
```

with

```
margin:auto;
```

**Full CSS**

```
#Content {
background-color: #006600;
margin:auto;
padding: 5px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: normal;
font-color: #000;
width: 1200px;
height: 850px;
}
```